# Populating differently sized DIMMs in HP ProLiant DL380 Gen10 server

Tags: configuration, memory, installation, hp-proliant

Trying to build an HPE ProLiant DL380 Gen10 server with a mix of HPE 16GB and 32GB DIMMs.

I've read the Server Maintenance and Service Guide, the Server User Guide and the Server Memory Population Rules white paper (https://h20195.www2.hpe.com/v2/GetDocument.aspx?docname=a00017079enw, pages 18-20), but can't figure out the correct configuration for these DIMMS.

I have 2 x 32GB DIMMs and 4 x 16GB DIMMs. Do I:

1. Install the 32GB DIMMs in (white) slots 1 & 3; install the 16GB DIMMs in (white) slots 5, 8, 10 & 12?
2. Install the 32GB DIMMs in (white) slots 1 & 3; install the 16GB DIMMs in (black) slots 6, 7, 9 & 11?
3. Something else?

Comment: Has the server got a single CPU socket or multiple socket motherboard? Do you have one or more CPUs?

Comment: 2 sockets with 12 DIMM slots each. I have 2 processors and exactly double the DIMM modules I described above. To keep the question simple, I described a single processor example. Now I come to think of it though, do I just use 4 x 32GB modules for 1 processor (in the 4-module configuration shown in the white paper) and 8 x 16GB modules for the other?

Comment: That would be the easy way :)

Comment: Doesn't work! The server won't allow a different number of DIMMs for each processor.